# Why does the shadow(formed at the bottom surface of beaker) of thumb disappear when it is at the interface of air and water?

Tags: optics

Switch on the light bulb of your room and take a beaker filled with water.Now,slowly drift your thumb towards the top surface of water,notice that a sharp shadow of thumb is formed at the bottom surface of beaker.When the thumb is just touching the interface separating air and water the shadow of some part of thumb disappears.Now dip the thumb in water,notice that the shadow of thumb reappears.

What happens at the interface which causes the shadow of thumb to disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydrophile + surface tension + refraction[image]